# How to add an EMF-model into another EMF-model as a package?

Tags: eclipse, model, reference, eclipse-emf, ecore

I have to EMF models. A and B.

A's elements reference B's various elements and the main model element from which I create the instances is in B, containing all the other model elements. Meaning that the main model is the B, and when I create an instance based on the B's main model element, I should be able create children in B-instance from A's referencing elements.

But since they happen to be in two different EMF projects, I want to add the A in B (somehow reference it from within the B maybe?), without just defining a new EPackage in B and copying the A into it. That is a design issue for right now, that both should be in different projects.

What is the best way to do it? Do you have any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generate your models using annotated interfaces, or if it is not possible write 2 new simple models (using annotated interfaces) just to see how it works. For example, write interfaces for model B in plugin B and generate model B. Write interfaces for model A in plugin A, in A's MANIFEST.MF add plugin B as a dependency and generate model A. Now in A.genmodel you'll see links to your main model B.

Comment: Mind if I ask, what you mean exactly with annotated interfaces?

Comment: Annotated interfaces are one of the ways to generate a EMF model. They look like Java interfaces with annotations (like @model) under Java comments . Others ways to generate a model are XML-schema definition, Rational Rose UML diagram, direct editing of .ecore file.